# Variance of a model Gaussian not equal to the actual parameter

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab

Why is it when I calculate a set of values with a gaussian function that has sigma 1, the resulting variance of the values doesn't equal 1?

E.g. in MATLAB I have:

```
g = @(x) exp(-(x.^2)/ 2) /sqrt(2*pi); %normalized 1D gaussian, variance = 1
x = linspace(-50,50,200); 
var(g(x)); %doesn't give 1, nor does sum(g(x))
```

What is the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 1):

The variance of a probability distribution $p(x)$ refers to its dispersion (or "width") in the dimension of $x$. What you're calculating here instead is the variance of the probabilities $p(x)$, i.e. the variance of the "y-values" of the distribution.

The variance of a probability distribution (or more accurately, of a *probability density function*) $p(x)$ is given by the following integral:
$$
\int x^2p(x)dx -\mu^2
$$
where $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution, defined as $\mu=\int xp(x)dx$.

Comment: I knew it was something simple, I came to a similar conclusion a few minutes after posting. Should I delete the question or just leave it and accept this?